# Is it necessary to report estimate of variance for a marginal likelihood estimation?

Tags: bayesian, variance, markov-chain-montecarlo, computational-statistics, marginal-distribution

There are several simulation based estimators for estimating marginal likelihood of data - Importance Sampling estimator, Newton Raftery estimator, Chib's method, Gelfand-Dey estimator etc. But while reporting the estimate (in articles or dissertations), the variance of those estimates very rarely get's reported.

I think reporting those variance estimates is as much necessary as reporting variance estimate of a parameter of interest a fitted model. Then why is it not the general practice ? Is it mainly because the computation of sample variance of a marginal likelihood estimator is tricky sometimes ?

Comment: Definitely necessary!